# iPhone 13 Pro: Enable macro mode in custom camera

Tags: ios, swift

Apple enabled the macro mode in the iphone 13 pro:
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210571

When you move close to an object (note: not only when zooming, but as well when just moving the phone closer), it switches to the ultra.wide camera.

I know that I can enable automatic switching by using .builtInTripleCamera.
However, it does not switch automatically just because I move the camera closer to an object. I think that is the magic behind the "macro mode".

I did not find anything in the docs - how can I enable the macro mode in my own camera app?

Comment: It should automatically switch to the ultra wide (macro) camera when moving the camera close to an object, no additional code is necessary. Please verify that the capture device really is using the .builtInTripleCamera (with .deviceType)

Comment: which framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you should use builtInTripleCamera or builtInDualWideCamera
and also add zoom like

```
device.videoZoomFactor = CGFloat(device.virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors.first ?? 1)
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't see how this is related to the question

Comment: Following apple forums thats the answer their developers gave, you should add some initial zoom that will make the effect you are looking for. im not sure why this is the behavior but its working pretty well

Comment: Interesting, could you share a link?

Answer (score 1):

Macro Control mode is implemented by locking the multi-cam device to stay at the ultra-wide camera when it should already switch to another camera according to it's zoom level.

Use the  [`setPrimaryConstituentDeviceSwitchingBehavior(_:restrictedSwitchingBehaviorConditions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/3875310-setprimaryconstituentdeviceswitc/) API to achieve that:

```swift
let currentZoom = device.videoZoomFactor

// 1. zoom out to ultra-wide camera
device.lockForConfiguration()
device.videoZoomFactor = device.minAvailableVideoZoomFactor
device.unlockForConfiguration()

device.lockForConfiguration()
// 2. lock multi-cam to stay at ultra-wide instead of switching over
device.setPrimaryConstituentDeviceSwitchingBehavior(.locked,
                                                    restrictedSwitchingBehaviorConditions: [])

// 3. zoom back to the previous state, now it will not switch camera devices though.
device.videoZoomFactor = currentZoom
device.unlockForConfiguration()
```

Comment: If it has been automatically switched to the Ultra-Wide camera, how to switch it back to wide camera just like the Camera app does.

Comment: Then lock it when it is in the wide-angle zoom state.

Comment: If the system has already switched over to ultra-wide camera, the system’s Camera app can switch back to the main camera via macro control button which **don’t need to wait for auto re-switching to the wide camera**. How can we achieve this programmatically?